# Wrong date being displayed when trying to parse a date

Tags: java, jodatime

When I run the following code, I get the output as

```
2016-01-10T06:00:06.000+05:30
```

but when I'm actually expecting the month to be 06 instead of 01.

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

    public class Test2 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String last_notified_date_fromDB_string = "2016-06-10 06:00:06";
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            System.out.println(formatter.parseDateTime(last_notified_date_fromDB_string));
        }
    }
```

Any idea as to why this is happening?
Thank you.

Comment: Use `y` and `d` for year and day :  `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `D` is a day of year (should be `d`).

Since the tenth day of year is in January, the month gets reset to `01`.